# How to move to a new fragment after clicking a button in a list item

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

How can I ensure that a button inside a list item is clickable, because I am trying to make the button clickable so that it can transition to a different fragment?

Like the listview and the list items inside it are part of a fragment and I want to ensure that clicking a specific button inside a list item will transition to the new fragment.

MainActivity Code:
It contains tabs(not all of which are implemented yet, but thats not an issue right now)

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements HomeFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {



    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //set up the tabs which hold different fragments, it will currently crash because of the null
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this,getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator("Home"), HomeFragment.class , null);
       // mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("search").setIndicator("Search"),null/*fragment here*/,null);
       // mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("post").setIndicator("Post"),null/*fragment here*/,null);
       // mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("books").setIndicator("Books"),null/*fragment here*/,null);
       // mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("me").setIndicator("Me"),null/*fragment here*/,null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //For home fragment...parameter might change
    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(String id) {

        Button viewPostings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.view_postings);
        viewPostings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PostDetailFragment fragment = PostDetailFragment.newInstance();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.realtabcontent, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Im trying to launch the new activity from the implementation of onFragmentInteractionListener. The app loads the list view and its contents, but the individual buttons in it aren't clickable.

Comment: Where is the code where you define the listview ?

Comment: Do you want both list view and list item code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you need to add this line to make the items in the custom list item clickable:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Add this property to the enclosing layout.

Secondly, you need to set the onClickListener in the getView method of the custom adapter that you have made for your custom ListView. For example, that would be something like this:

```
ImageButton deleteBtn = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);
deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // code here
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why do you need android:descendantFocusability ?

Comment: So would the fragment trasactions happen in the onClick implementation? I am new to this so, I am not sure

Comment: So inside the getView, this is what I did: Button viewPostings = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.view_postings);
            viewPostings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    PostDetailFragment fragment = PostDetailFragment.newInstance();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.realtabcontent, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                }
            });    but it is unable to resolve getSupportFragmentManager()

Answer (score 0):

Use some sort of [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) such as an [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) to populate your ListView. That way, you can use the adapter to handle the button clicks.

Comment: when you say button clicks, do you mean button clicks inside a list item?

Comment: Yeah. You handle each list item's population in the adapter, so you can handle each list item's button.

Answer (score 0):

In your list fragment, use the onItemClick:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (null != mListener) {
        // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
        // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(foodList.get(position));
    }
}
```

Then in your parent activity, you will have something like this.

```
@Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Food food) {
        //going from ListFragment to DetailFragment
        //call detail fragment here
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment fragment = DetailFragment.newInstance(food);
        ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack( "tag" );
        ft.commit();
    }
```